# When to login into gspread while executing an endless python script

Tags: python, google-api

I dont know when it is optimal to login into gspread while exectuing my python script endlessly.

```
def openSheet(sheetName):
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open(sheetName).sheet1
    return sheet
```

As of right now I am executing the openSheet method every time I am requesting a file from gspread.

But to optimize performance of my script I thought I can define scope, creds and client at the top of my script so that it gets defined only once and not every time the endless loop gets executed.

When should I execute the login?

Answer (score 0):

That is what I have done. I have scope, creds, and client immediately below my import statements, so that when I get to the functions in my script that are called repeatedly, I only have to include the portion that defines the sheet (random_variable_name = gc.open('my_spreadsheet') when I want to call a file.

For example, mine looks something like this;

```
import gspread
from google.colab import auth 
auth.authenticate_user()
from google.colab import drive
import gspread 
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

scope = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]

json_file = 'myfilepath/uberimportantstuff.json'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(json_file, scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

At this point, all I have to do is below to create the object.

```
sh = gc.open(spreadsheet_name)
```